# Wordpress does not recognize logged users

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom page template that is only accessible to certain user roles. If a visitor is not logged in or is not of given role, he gets redirected to the login page.

The problem is, if the user tries to access this page prior to logging in, he gets redirected anyway (after login) - problem gets only solved after clearing browser data and relogging. This does not occur if the user logs in first and then tries to access the page.

```
function ts_restrict_user_access() {

    if ( is_page_template( 'templates/ts-sample.php' ) ) {

        $redirect = true;

        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

            $user = wp_get_current_user();

            if ( in_array( 'worker', (array) $user->roles ) || in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles )) {
                $redirect = false;
            }
        } 

        if ( $redirect ) {
            wp_redirect( esc_url( home_url( '/login' ) ), 301 );
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using some sort of caching plugin thats caching the response? Also I dont think you need the $redirect variable and logic to handle it.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have any active plugins, besides of what I'm building, however, I am using this snippet for templating from within a plugin: http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using any caching plugin, disable it and give your code a try again.

I've simplified your code a bit, please see below.

```
function ts_restrict_user_access() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'templates/ts-sample.php' ) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $allowed_roles = array('worker', 'administrator');
        if (!array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) {
            wp_redirect( esc_url( home_url( '/login' ) ), 301 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't have any active plugins, besides of what I'm building, however, I am using this snippet for templating from within a plugin: http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/

Comment: Stupid mistake that costed me a lot of time -.- After changing redirect to 302 it works just fine.